# What does "(Downloaded)" mean before the description of some plasmids and tonics?

Tags: bioshock

Some tonics/plasmids in Gatherer's Gardens say "(Downloaded)" before their descriptions and only cost 1 ADAM. What does this mean?

[image: Sonic Boom in a Gatherer's Garden]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are part of Downloadable Content you have installed. In the case of Sonic Boom that's the **1.1 Patch**, which registers as a DLC.

The 1.1 Patch includes [a variety of other changes](http://www.bioshockgame.com/support/) - I have marked the plasmid additions:

> - Added compatibility with Matrox TripleHead2Go - Allows Bioshock users to play in Surround Gaming Mode across 3 screens simultaneously
> - Added rendering support for TripleHead2Go
> - *Added the following plasmids and gene tonics: Sonic Boom, Sonic Boom 2, Eve Saver, Machine Buster, Machine Buster 2, Vending Expert, Vending Expert 2*
> - Added an Option to disable the Vita-Chambers for added difficulty.
> - Changed behavior of subtitles so that inappropriate queuing is improved
> - Added support for a walk toggle keybind
> - Added Horizontal FOV Lock option
> - Atlas VO volume increased for German releases